# Function help combining multiple vars

Tags: javascript, beginner

I am very new to JS and am having a bit of a problem with making this happen.

```
function updateDisplay23() {

  var statElem = document.getElementById("stat_ht");

  if (statElem) {

    statElem.innerHTML = stats["ht"];

  }

}
```

I load all the functions from the index at the startup then call the function with:

```
updateDisplay23()
```

This works fine and loads the info to the index page as desired. The problem is I have 30 or so functions, and may add many more. This is a lot of calls, I would like to combine them all into one function call.  Someone hinted this may be possible.

Comment: How do these 30 functions differ from each other? Do they all do similar things? If not, it's totally fine - javascript programs often contain way more than 30 functions (although they are named distinctly, and never numbered).

Answer (score 2):

Every function needs to be called to run. If you have 30 functions you need to call them all but if you want to call them only once you can do something like this:

```
            var callThemAll = function() {
                function1();
                function2();
                // call them all like this
            }
```

But there is also a 'lazy way' if I could call it like that. We create an object and these functions will become it's methods and we can iterate over them:

```
         var objWithFunctions = {
            myFirstFunction: function() {
                // code here
            }
            // rest of your functions
        }

        for(fn in objWithFunctions) {
            objWithFunctions[fn].call();
        }
        // all methods are being called
```

I wrote a full example here: http://jsbin.com/gaseti/1/

**Edit:**
After seeing your code(you posted it somewhere) the difference bettwen your function are just 2 strings.
You can make only one function with 2 parameters:

You can insert this into your code

```
            function updateDisplay(param1, param2) {

              var statElem = document.getElementById(param1);

              if (statElem) {

                statElem.innerHTML = stats[param2];

              }

            }
```

Call like this:

```
            updateDisplay("stat_ht", "ht");
```

Now, to call them all we could do this. Save all parameters into 2 separated arrays

`var param1s = ["stat_ht","stat_ht","stat_ht"], param2s = ["ht","ht","ht"];`

Call updateDisplay for each of this

```
            if(param1s.length == param2s.length) {
                for(var i = 0; i <= params1.length; i++) {
                    updateDisplay(param1s[i], param2s[i]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you I will try and make this work. :)                               *edit So where do I write the arrays? Sorry just learning this stuff. Thanks. With this setup am I still able to call them by using the *script command?

Comment: Never mind I see from your comment I still use the *script just just not about adding the arrays. Thanks.

Comment: The code is to long to post I can offer a link to the game so you can view the source code. Thank you all for your help so far. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80005171/Main%20copy%20Norif/web/mygame/index.html It is still in the early stages of development

Comment: What do you mean by *script command ?

Comment: During the game the player will make choices and the choices are updated to the index page. I do this by *script updateDisplay23() as an example.

Comment: The main funtions of the game are setup in javascript, it calls the pages I call in to the page. Inside the game it uses choicescript. I cannot use javascript in the game function, but can call functions with the *script command such as *script updateDisplay23() or *script document.getElementById("story_image").src="pics/maps/world.jpg";

Comment: choicescript will not allow for arrays so I have to set them up outside the game as I do the functions, just not sure where or how to do so.

Comment: Yeah, just put them outside and them call them with *script

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. So I make a .js file then load it in the index like I do the function?

Comment: Yes, but use only one .js file :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that calls every other function or have a parameter such as:

```
callFunction(23);
```

And then you can use a switch statement to choose which ones. The default statement within the switch could be used to call all of the functions.

**Update:** I was told that you could also use an array to store the functions. An array would be far more efficient to code.

```
callFunction[23];
```

Comment: That still sounds like you'd have 30 similar function declarations. Adding a `callFunction` that lists all of them in a `switch` statement is not an improvement.

Comment: It allows for easier management. The only other solution would be to consolidate the other functions into one function. But if the functions need to be called individually then a callFunction would be the logical choice.

Comment: @pisquaredtau: No. Just putting them in an array `updateDisplay[23]` is the logical choice for that.

Comment: An array instead of a switch?